# SwiftUI change view from first screen to tabview screen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I want to change views once the user taps 'get started' but due to having navigation view in my first view, it is showing back button on my next screen which I don't want. Please see the images attached below.

Code for the first view is below:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("LifePath")
                .font(.system(size: 48, weight: .semibold))
                .padding(.bottom)
            Spacer()
            
            
            
            NavigationLink(destination: ViewChanger()) {
                Text("Get Started")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

}

[back button showing on screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4x95.png)

[First view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7gk2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change the location of your `navigationBackButtonHidden` modifier so that it actually modifies the view that you're going to (and not the `NavigationLink` label):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("LifePath")
                    .font(.system(size: 48, weight: .semibold))
                    .padding(.bottom)
                Spacer()
                
                
                
                NavigationLink(destination: ViewChanger()
                                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true) // <-- Here
                ) {
                    Text("Get Started")
                        .font(.headline)
                        
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

If you want not only the back button to be gone, but the entire header bar, you can use the `.navigationBarHidden(true)` modifier.

Also, if you run this on iPad at all, you probably want `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` added to the outside of your `NavigationView`

Answer (score 0):

If you use a NavigationLink (in a NavigationView), the view will be pushed. If you want to replace the view, you can do this with an `if` statement.

For example, this could be implemented like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSecondView: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        if !showSecondView {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("LifePath")
                        .font(.system(size: 48, weight: .semibold))
                        .padding(.bottom)
                    Spacer()
            
                    Button(action: { showSecondView = true }) {
                        Text("Get Started")
                            .font(.headline)
                    }
            }
            .padding()
        } else {
            TabView {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```